# REACT NATIVE: How can I access a screen from a Tap-navigator that is inside a Stack-Navigator

Tags: react-native, navigation

I currently have a stack navigator :

```
export default StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: BottomBarNavigator },
}, stackNavigatorConfig);

export default BottomBarNavigator({
    Home: { screen: TapNavigator },
    Notification : { screen : NotifiationsScreen},
}, stackNavigatorConfig);
```

On the Home screen of my App, I have a Tab Navigator with two screens.

```
export default TapNavigator({
    screen1 : { screen: screen1 },
    screen2 : { screen : screen2 },
}, stackNavigatorConfig);
```

How can I navigate from my Stacknavigator to screen 2 from my TapNavigator?

```
StackNavigator -> BottombarNavigator -> TapNavigator -> screen 2
```

Comment: you had the typo `scree2` but I've edited that to `screen2` + fix your code formatting.